# How to download images from universe roboflow?

Tags: roboflow

I want to download all the labelled images from https://universe.roboflow.com/malik-kashif-saeed-aswwf/wild-animals-id35k, I see that there is a dataset available, but it includes some augmentation and pre-processing that I want to avoid.
Is it possible to download the labelled images directly from https://universe.roboflow.com/malik-kashif-saeed-aswwf/wild-animals-id35k/images ?